# WPF nested datagrids. Multiple levels

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to create table editor for multi-level table data using standard wpf datagrid.
Is it possible to create nested structure something like this?

[image: Syncfusion datagrid]

With standard row details nested grids looks ugly, because row details must have fixed height (so i will get multiple scrolls)

[image: My demo application]

Comment: You might go at this with a treeview and templates.

Answer (score 8):

Each `DataGrid` can have something called a `RowDetailsTemplate`.  The template can have anything you want in it, including another `DataGrid`.  If that `DataGrid` uses the same `RowDetailsTemplate`, you can have a `DataGrid` nested inside a `DataGrid` ad-infinitum.

Check out [this article](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/) for an example of using the `RowDetailsTemplate`.  You just need to modify the XAML there to use your own template.

Comment: but what about multiple scroll bars? is it possible to stretch rowdetails height to fit content height?

Comment: @cmd I've never tried that.  I suppose you could bind the `Height` of the `DataGrid` in the `RowDetailsTemplate` to a property of the row in it.  You'd have to recursively loop through all of the objects in that nested object which populates the nested `DataGrid` in order to figure out the height.