# How to create in a wpf datagrid something similar to the related records in a Microsoft Access table

Tags: ms-access, datagrid

In a table of Microsoft Access when you have related data, each record in the left side has a "+" symbol, when you hit it, it shows the related data of that record.
[Example of the Acces table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH4vz.png)

I look up in diferent places but found nothing related to how can I do it in a wpf datagrid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF nested datagrids. Multiple levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935910/wpf-nested-datagrids-multiple-levels)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058677/wpf-how-to-access-nested-grid